# Symfony/Doctrine - Force Add Where Clause Parameter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is there a way to add a parameter (condition) in every `where` clause by default? For example, if normal query is `select * from abc where col1 = 2` then I want to add `AND col100 = somevalue` to the above query when symfony/doctrine executes the query.

So whatever type of query system executes (select, update, delete) one additional column should be added at the time of execution.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL filter is what you're looking for, see e.g.:

http://culttt.com/2014/08/11/working-doctrine-2-filters/

or within the official documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html

Comment: Rather than just links to information, which can go away, it's good practice to at least summarise the relevant information.

Comment: @AlisterBulman I agree with you - in this special case a simple google search would have delivered the answer - so instead of just downvoting this question I decided to provide exactly the information he required. Will take more attention next time.